# Number of inversions with merge sort: Why do I not need to initialize a global variable here?

Tags: python

I implemented merge sort in python and am trying to get the number of inversions of a given array. An inversion is defined as a pair of indices 0 ≤  <  <  such that  > . This problem is also described as 'how far away is an array from being sorted'.

Here is my code:

```
def merge(a,b):
    c = [] # Output array
    i, j = 0, 0 # Indices of the left and right split arrays

    global num_inversions
    # It looks like there is no need to initialize this? I don't understand this
    
    while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
        if a[i] <= b[j]:
            c.append(a[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            c.append(b[j])
            j += 1
            num_inversions = num_inversions + len(a) - i
            
    if i == len(a):
        c.extend(b[j:])
    else:
        c.extend(a[i:])

    return c


def mergesort(a):
    # Base case
    if len(a) <= 1:
        return a
    
    mid = len(a) // 2
    
    left_array = mergesort(a[:mid])
    right_array = mergesort(a[mid:])
    
    return merge(left_array, right_array)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #inp = input()
    #n, *a = list(map(int, inp.split()))
    
    a = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] # Sample input. Gives the correct answer 15
    a_sorted = mergesort(a)
    print(num_inversions)
```

I seem to be getting the correct result. What I don't understand is why the global variable num_inversions can be declared in the function, and why it doesn't need to be initialized.

Initializing it in the function is obviously wrong because the value will keep getting rewritten each time the function is called recursively.

Edit: Sorry, this question was incredibly stupid. I realized I did initialize it at some point while testing it, and forgot.

Comment: You DO need to initialize `num_inversions` - a `global` statement by itself just ensures the name gets interpreted as a global, it doesn't assign any value.  You must have assigned a value *somewhere*, or this code would produce a `NameError`.

Comment: @jasonharper You're right, I've edited the post to reflect this. Should I leave the post alone or answer my own question? I am new and unfamiliar with stackoverflow etiquette and keep getting downvoted.

Comment: Well, normally you would just delete such a question. Any reputation changes that you got from it (downwards, but ___also upwards___ !!!) will be reversed.